# How can I make four different timestamps on the same sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to use 4 different timestamps in a sheet based on columns titled timestamp 1 / timestamp 2. When the box is checked then the timestamp moves into the sequence column. Here is my script for the first chart. How can I make it for all four charts on that page? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11AQMvhWbzgmLLPbdf94nW7D_Kkb1aQefrU755AOhkJo/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(event) {
  const timezone = 'GMT-5';
  const timestamp_format = 'HH:mm:ss'; // Timestamp Format.
  const updateColName = 'Time Stamp 1';
  const timeStampColName = 'Sequence 1';
  const sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Experiment - Training w/ Duration'); // Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.
  const actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  const editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  const index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  let updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol += 1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    const cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem.  Go ahead use as many as you like.

Comment: You script automatically inserts a timestamp with the actual date the moment you perform an edit in any cell in updateCol, you can create as many timestamps as you want by editing the cells.

Comment: Welcome. Use [`offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) to build `setValue` range. Column offset is always 2, the row offset is always 0 (zero). tldr; You have four checkboxes but you don't know which will be edited; establish the spacial relationships between each checkbox and its related timestamp so that, knowing the checkbox location, the timestamp location can be calculated. Checkboxes = either Column A or J, and either row 11 or 12; use Event objects to get the actual column and row.

Comment: Thank you for sharing these things. I think my problem is that I don't know how. I copied this script from someone and edited a few of the specific rows and columns that I could figure out. I just don't know which others to edit as I have absolutely zero experience with writing scripts. Would it be a possibility for you to edit my script to accomplish what you've just shared with me (i.e. when I select the check box in row 11 or 12 in column A, J, S, AB - it would timestamp in the same row of 11 or 12 in the column C, L, U, AD respectively.)